# Building Out a Function that returns a number of votes from 1-5, based on a average and number of votes

Tags: javascript, math

Hey smarter people than I,

I'm currently working on a function that will build out what would appear to be a real amount of review ratings, in the form of an object, given an average rating(1-5) and a number of reviews(any). I'm trying to figure out the best way of handling this since I don't have access to each individual vote, I'm trying to build the votes in such a way it still meets the average. Here's what I've developed, however, I currently have a bug in which all of the votes go to the avg and they're not spread out as I would like even though I specifically target the number of votes towards each by multiplying by a decimal and using math.round to escape decimals.

What do y'all think? Is there a better way that I can explore this?

```
let avg = Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1);
console.log('Current Avg is',avg);
let numberOfVotes = Math.round(Math.random()*50)
console.log('Current Number of Votes is',numberOfVotes);

function buildSomeFakeNums (avg,numberofvotes){
  avg = Math.round(avg);
let votes = {
  1:0,
  2:0,
  3:0,
  4:0,
  5:0,
}

// -------------- Handling Averages ----------
  //1 or 5
  if (avg === 1 || 5){
    votes[avg] = numberofvotes;
    return votes;
  }
  //2
  if (avg === 2){
    votes[1] = Math.round(numberofvotes * .20);
    votes[avg] = Math.round(numberofvotes * .60);
    votes[3] = Math.round(numberofvotes * .15);
    votes[4] = Math.round(numberofvotes * .05);
  }
  //3
  if (avg === 3){
    votes[1] = Math.round(numberofvotes * .05);
    votes[2] = Math.round(numberofvotes * .15);
    votes[avg] = Math.round(numberofvotes *.60);
    votes[4] = Math.round(numberofvotes * .15);
    votes[5] = Math.round(numberofvotes * .05);
  }
  //4
  if (avg === 4){
    votes[2] = Math.round(numberofvotes * .05);
    votes[3] = Math.round(numberofvotes * .15);
    votes[avg] = Math.round(numberofvotes *.60);
    votes[5] =Math.round( numberofvotes * .20);
  }
  console.log(votes)
  return votes;
}

buildSomeFakeNums(avg,numberOfVotes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from this line: `if (avg === 1 || 5){` because it will always be true (5 is considered true).

Replace it by `if (avg === 1 || avg === 5){` and it should work.